# Symmetry in function given by double sum

Tags: functions, polynomials, summation, hypergeometric-function

I had to deal with this function:

$$ f_n(x_1,x_2)=(x_2-x_1)^{n-1}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-m-1}C(n,m,j)\left(\frac{x_2}{x_2-x_1}\right)^m\left(\frac{x_2(1-x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\right)^j $$
where 
$$C(n,m,j)=\frac{(-n+1)_m}{m!}\frac{(-n+m+1)_j(n)_j}{j!(m+2)_j}$$
or
$$C(n,m,j)=\frac{(-1)^{m+j}(n+j-1)!(m+1)}{j!(n-m-j-1)!(m+j+1)!}$$

(Here $(x)_j=x(x+1)\cdots (x+j-1)$ is the Pochhammer symbol or rising factorial).

I computed several cases and it seems that $f_n(x_1,x_2)$ is a symmetic function for every $n$, even though that is not apparent at first sight. Can one bring the function to another form that is explicitly symmetric?

I have tried playing with hypergeometric identites, but there are so many of them and I didn't get anywhere.

EDIT:

Playing with particular cases, it seems the function is given by
$$f_n(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^iA_{i,j}x_1^{n-1-i+j}x_2^{n-j}$$
and some of the coefficients are recognizable:

$$A_{i,1}=A_{i,i}={2n-i-1\choose n-1}{n-1\choose n-i}\frac{1}{(n-i+1)}$$
and
$$A_{n,j}={n-1\choose j-1}{n\choose j-1}\frac{1}{j}$$

Comment: Why is this surprising? If the original function is a symmetric polynomial in $x_1$ and $x_2$, then it is a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials $x_1+x_2=\gamma$ and $x_1x_2=\xi$.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you may have a typo in your original expression for $f_n(x_1,x_2)$, as it doesn't seem to be symmetric. Perhaps the term
$$\left(\frac{x_2}{x_2-x_1}\right)^m
\qquad\text{ should be }\qquad
\left(\frac{x_1(1-x_2)}{x_2-x_1}\right)^m?$$

Comment: @Servaes You are right that the actual point is whether the function is symmetric. There is no typo so the symmetry is not obvious. I reformulated the question to focus on that problem. Thank you.

Comment: there is not a generally accepted definition of the Pochhammer symbol: do you mean the falling or the rising factorial version ?

Comment: @GCab edited, thanks.

Comment: @Servaes How did you arrive at that simplification? I do not think it is correct. The $x_2^{n-1}$ terms of the function agree with your formula, but you are missing the other powers of $x_2$

Comment: @thedude You are right, I misread the indexing of the inner sum. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Servaes but you did capture part of the function, so maybe you were on the right track...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me change a bit your notation and put
$$
\eqalign{
  & g(x,y,n) = \left( {y - x} \right)^{\,n} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n - k} {
 D(n,k,j)\left( {{y \over {y - x}}} \right)^{\,k + j} \left( {1 - x} \right)^{\,j} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {y - x} \right)^{\,n} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{k\, \le \,j + k\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,i\,\left( { \le \,j} \right)} {
 \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,i} \binom{j+k-k}{i} D(n,k,j){{y^{\,k + j} \,x^{\,i} } \over {\left( {y - x} \right)^{\,k + j} }}} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {y - x} \right)^{\,n} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{k\, \le \,l\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,i\,\left( { \le \,j} \right)} {
 \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,i} \binom{ l - k }{i} D(n,k,l){{y^{\,l} \,x^{\,i} } \over {\left( {y - x} \right)^{\,l} }}} } }  \cr} 
$$
where 
$$
\eqalign{
  & D(n,k,j) = {{\left( { - n} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}}{{\left( { - \left( {n - k} \right)} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } } \over {j!\left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} n^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}}{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( {n - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,j\,} } \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } } \over {j!\left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + j} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - k \cr 
  n - \left( {k + j} \right) \cr}  \right){{\left( {k + 2 + \left( {n - k} \right) - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } } \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + j} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - k \cr 
  n - \left( {k + j} \right) \cr}  \right){{\left( {k + 2 + \left( {n - k} \right) - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } } \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,j\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + j} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - k \cr 
  n - \left( {k + j} \right) \cr}  \right){{\left( {k + j + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } } \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } }} \cr} 
$$

We can then replace $k+j$ with $l$
$$
D(n,k,l) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{n-l}
{{\left( {l + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } } \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } }}
$$

Note that the bounds
$$
0\le k \le n  \quad
k\le l \le n
$$
are implicit in the binomials and can therefore be virtually omitted 
in the sum for $g(x,y,n)$

Thereafter, some further algebraic manipulation on 
the above expression leads to:
$$
\eqalign{
  & D(n,k,l) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - k \cr 
  n - l \cr}  \right){{\left( {l + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } } \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} {{n^{\,\underline {\,\left( {n - k} \right)\,} } } \over {\left( {n - k} \right)!}}{{\left( {n - k} \right)!} \over {\left( {n - l} \right)!
 \left( {l - k} \right)!}}{{\left( {n - k + l} \right)^{\,\underline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } } \over {n^{\,\underline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} {{n^{\,\underline {\,\left( {n - k} \right)\,} } } \over {\left( {n - l} \right)!\left( {l - k} \right)!}}{{
\left( {n - k + l} \right)^{\,\underline {\,\left( {n - k} \right) - 1\,} } } \over {n^{\,\underline {\,\left( {n - k} \right)\,} } k^{\,\underline {\, - 1\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} {{\left( {n + l - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,\left( {n - k} \right)\,} } } \over {\left( {n - l} \right)!
\left( {l - k} \right)!}}{{l^{\,\underline {\, - 1\,} } } \over {k^{\,\underline {\, - 1\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  n + l - k \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n - k \cr 
  l - k \cr}  \right){{k + 1} \over {l + 1}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  n + l - k \cr 
  l - k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  n - l \cr}  \right){{k + 1} \over {l + 1}} \cr} 
$$

Adding the multiplying binomial, the complete factor becomes
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(n,k,l,i) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,i} \binom{l-k}{i} D(n,k,l) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,i} \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \binom{l-k}{i}
 \binom{n+l-k}{l-k} \binom{n}{n-l}
{{k + 1} \over {l + 1}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - i} \binom{n+l-k}{l-k}  \binom{l-k}{l-k-i}  \binom{n}{n-l}   {{k + 1} \over {l + 1}} =   \cr 
  &  = \binom{n+l-k}{l-i-k} \binom{k+1}{k}
 \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - i} \binom{n+i}{i} \binom{n}{n-l}{1 \over {l + 1}} \cr} 
$$

Note that we have manouvred in such a way as to group the
terms in $k$. We can therefore sum $F(n,k,l,i)$ over $k$
using the "double convolution formula" for binomials.
Let's remember that the bounds on the sum can be waived
thus allowing to carry on the convolution without 
caring to check them.

So we get
$$
\eqalign{
  & G(n,l,i) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {F(n,k,l,i)}  =   \cr 
  & \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - i} \binom{n+i}{i} \binom{n}{n-l}
  {1 \over {l + 1}}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,l - i} \right)} {
  \binom{n + l - k}{  l - i - k} \binom{  k + 1}{  k } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - i} \binom{  n + i}{  i }\binom{  n}{  n - l } {1 \over {l + 1}}\binom{  n + l + 2 }{  l - i }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - i} \binom{  n + i }{  i}\binom{  n }{  l } {1 \over {l + 1}}\binom{  n + l + 2 }{  l - i }   =   \cr 
  &  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - i} {1 \over {n + 1}}\binom{  n + i }{  i } \binom{  n + 1 }{  l + 1} \binom{  n + l + 2}{  l - i}  \cr} 
$$

I suppose that from here you can conclude by yourself.